# Error while moving pimcore 1.4.10 from server to local

Tags: zend-framework, pimcore

This is the first time I'm using pimcore.

I'm trying to move an application built on work, to continue working on local and get this error:

```
Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: No route, document, custom route or redirect is matching the request: / | Specific ERROR: No route matched the request in /home/koko/Training/application/pimcore/lib/Pimcore.php on line 253
```

I don't know how to fix this issue. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Was it working at work?

Comment: Did you check the custom routing in pimcore? And do you get this error on frontend or in the backend? Plus have you checked your .htaccess? Plus have you checked the permissions? Plus: have you tried updating your pimcore? 1.4.10 is pretty old.

Comment: can you provide some more details? serverconfig, how did you copy the pimcore installation, how did you copy the database?

Comment: This question is expired since there is already version 11. And Pimcore is not based on Zend anymore but on Symfony.